# Loading a png into a UIImageView iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, png

I have two images that need to be overlaid over one another, and they are both png images (since I need to be able to make them transparent).  However, when I load them into a UIImage view in my xib file, neither of them display at all!  When I try using the jpg format of the same images it works fine, but because jpg doesn't support transparency, the overlay effect I need is lost.  How can I get the png images to actually display in the window?

[image: Interface Builder]

Comment: Screenshot of interface builder, please?

Comment: There are cases of png files that iOS cannot display. So when you use then in the xib file, you have also included the images in the project, and the images are included in the target (you looked at the right pan). In code, try to get the image [UIImage imageNamed:foo.png]; and see if it loads. Try configuring the imageViews.image with the image you just got from imageNamed. Try to open the images in Preview on the Mac, to verify you can see them there.

Comment: You should uncheck `opaque` if you want to overlay images using alpha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the kind of task that is easier to do from code than from Interface "Crappy" Builder:

```
CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

UIImage *image1 = // however you obtain your 1st image
UIImage *image2 = // however you obtain your 2nd image

UIImageView *imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
// Adjust the alpha of the view
imgView1.alpha = 1.0f; // This is most advisably 1.0 (always)
imgView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
imgView1.frame = imageFrame;

UIImageView *imgView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image2];
// Adjust the alpha of the view
imgView1.alpha = 0.5f; // or whatever you find practical
imgView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
imgView2.frame = imageFrame;

// Assume a view controller
[self.view addSubview:imgView1];
[self.view addSUbview:imgView2]; // add the image view later which you wanna be on the top of the other one

// If non-ARC environment, we need to take care of the percious RAM
[imgView1 release];
[imgView2 release];
```

Comment: I re-added the images to the project and built it programmatically and now it works! thanks!

Comment: @JulianColtea no problem. Note it well -- I have several reputatble iOS projects and I have never used Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open your png images in a photo editor like photoshop or pixelmator and save it again as NOT interlaced (in the save options of png).